# exception while getting resoponse from server: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I want to send and receive JSON data (long file) in my MVC application. I am using code shown below to make a call. But receiving error at GetResponse(). see error below. Server is receiving a call from my application but payload is not attached with it. I couldn't figure out why it's not attaching data with a call. Please confirm if my code is correct or missing something. Thank you in advance for help.

I have tried sending JSON without encoding.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
req.Accept = "application/json";
req.Method = "POST";
req.KeepAlive = true;
UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
Byte[] bytes = utf8.GetBytes(JSONRequest);
req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream newstream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
  newstream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  newstream.Close();
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
using (var responsestream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
  //var jsonresult = new StreamReader(responsestream);
  var cotentresult = responsestream.ReadToEnd();
  responsecontent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoanAcctInfoResponse>(cotentresult);
}
```

> Message:  Exception:
>
> ## Internal Server Error
>
> ### CICS TS:
>   Unhandled Pipeline Error
>
> #### Release: 700
>
> Message: 
>   Error while performing web request: The remote server returned an
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error. at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          at RevolvingCalculator_PaymentCalculator_.BusinessServices.LoanInfoFromWebService.PerformWebRequesttest(String JSONRequenter code hereest, String serviceUrl) in
>   C:\Development\HgProject\RevolvingCalculatorRepository\BusinessServices\LoanInfoFromWebService.cs:line
>   419
>       9/7/2019 9:00:21 PM    Message:  exception while getting resoponse from server: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal
>   Server Error.
>       stack trace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at *.PerformWebRequesttest(String JSONRequest, String serviceUrl) in *\BusinessServices\L*Service.cs:line 419   response: System.Net.HttpWebResponse ProtocolError
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in the code on the server you are calling.  And if that's the case, then the code you have shown us here is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for response. I am making a service call to external company so no idea what their process or code is. If I use the same JSON service from Soap UI, It is working fine. They can see my call but can't see payload.

Comment: The problem here (unless I am missing something) is that you are asking us to debug an error being thrown on a remote server to which you have no access. Check everything you can that is within your control. Example: is the JSON inside `JSONRequest` valid?  Does it comply with the format they expect?

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to confirm that the code I have written is correct or I am missing something and you answered that so appreciate it. I confirmed, the JSON is in valid format.

Comment: Ok, so at this point, I would try to reach out to whoever is hosting the remote server and report this problem to them.